# Add values to a Scipy sparse matrix with indexes and values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm working in a program for Power System analysis and I need to work with sparse matrices.

There is a routine where I fill a sparse matrix just with the following call:

```
self.A = bsr_matrix((val, (row,col)), shape=(nele, nbus), dtype=complex)
```

As this matrix won't change over time. Yet another matrix does change over time and I need to update it. Is there a way that having, for example:

```
co     = [ 2, 3, 6]
row    = [ 5, 5, 5]
val    = [ 0.1 + 0.1j, 0.1 - 0.2j, 0.1 - 0.4j]
```

I can *add* those to a previously initialized sparse matrix? How would be the more pythonic way to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a `coo_matrix` instead, where you can change the attributes `col`, `row` and `data` of a previously created sparse matrix:

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
nele=30
nbus=40
col    = [ 2, 3, 6]
row    = [ 5, 5, 5]
val    = [ 0.1 + 0.1j, 0.1 - 0.2j, 0.1 - 0.4j]
test = coo_matrix((val, (row,col)), shape=(nele, nbus), dtype=complex)

print test.col
#[2 3 6]
print test.row
#[5 5 5]
print test.data
#[ 0.1+0.1j  0.1-0.2j  0.1-0.4j]
```

Comment: Thank you. I read in the documentation that:

_By default when converting to CSR or CSC format, duplicate (i,j) entries will be summed together. This facilitates efficient construction of finite element matrices and the like. (see example)_

That more or less solves the problem that I had. In my code, there are several objects that contribute to this matrix and two objects can contribute to the same (i,j) entry.

This means that every time I want to add the contribution of one object I have to rebuild the matrix?

Comment: hi... yes, you can use the different objects to build the matrix just by assigning the `col` and `row` parameters to the `coo_matrix`. I am not sure though whether `SciPy` will create or not an internal copy when building the sparse matrix